# Remove Path after CGContextAddPath

Tags: ios, cocoa, cgcontext

I was wondering if there is a way to remove a CGPath from my context after I added it using the CGContextAddPath such that my drawing commands are no longer limited to the path dimensions afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `CGContextBeginPath(...)` to remove the previously added path from the specified context.

Discussion for the method from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextBeginPath):

> A graphics context can have only a single path in use at any time. If the specified context already contains a current path when you call this function, Quartz discards the old path and any data associated with it.
>
> The current path is not part of the graphics state. Consequently, saving and restoring the graphics state has no effect on the current path.

Similar to below:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddPath(context, ellipsePath);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

CGContextBeginPath(context);

CGContextAddPath(context, strokePath);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove a path once it is in the context. Just redraw without that particular path.